# LINQ to XML extract based on condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following repetitive XML structure from which I have to create a List of an object:

```
<entries>
    <entry>
        <start>2013-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</start>
        <end>2013-11-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</end>
        <value>27.02</value>
        <isExtracted>true</isExtracted>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <start>2013-11-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</start>
        <end>2013-12-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</end>
        <value>27.02</value>
        <isExtracted>true</isExtracted>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <start>2013-12-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</start>
        <end>2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</end>
        <value>27.02</value>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

I would like to extract only those elements that has the isExtracted xml tag!

What I do at the moment is the following:

```
    var extract = xElemMaster.Elements("entries").Elements("entry")
                        .Where(elem => elem.Name.Equals("isExtracted"));
```

But I'm not getting any results out. What might have probably gone wrong?

Comment: here is some `MSDN documentation` you can checkout also save yourself some time and do a google search `Linq to XML Tutorials` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx

Comment: It is interesting why would you expect one of elements selected by `Elements("entry")` to have different name... It is really good idea to split your query into one statement steps and check out results of each...

Comment: Won't you check when IsExtracted == false too?

Comment: Note the exact meaning behind `Elements()` -> "Get me all subnodes with that name". `Elements("entry")` isn't returning `<start>, <end>`, it's returning all `<entry>` nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Any` method

```
 xElemMaster.Elements("entries")
            .Elements("entry")
            .Where(elem => elem.Elements("isExtracted").Any());
```

Or just try to get element and check for null:

```
xElemMaster.Elements("entries")
            .Elements("entry")
            .Where(elem => elem.Element("isExtracted") != null);
```

To make it more readable I would create an extension method and use it instead:

```
public static bool HasElement(this XElement source, string elementName)
{
      return source.Element(elementName) != null;
}

xElemMaster.Elements("entries")
            .Elements("entry")
            .Where(elem => elem.Element.HasElement("isExtracted"));
```

Comment: That sound's reasonable. If I now want to select all the isExtracted, how is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can search nodes and subnodes with `Descendants`, then use `Any` to check if IsExtracted exists.

```
var extract = xElemMaster.Descendants("entry")   
                .Where(w=>w.Elements("isExtracted").Any())
```

You might also want to check if isExtracted==True or false

```
 var extract = x.Descendants("entry")
            .Where(w => w.Elements("isExtracted").Any() && w.Element("isExtracted").Value=="true");
```